# How to get pixel color of VectorDrawableCompat by specified x and y coordinates

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I have VectorDrawableCompat set as a background of my view.

I need to **handle a click** on this view only if I clicked on a **non-transparent** area of drawable.

For BitmapDrawable is pretty simple - I could just check getPixel(x, y), what I could do about it with VectorDrawableCompat?

Comment: draw your `Drawable` on the temporary `Bitmap` then

Comment: @pskink it will work, but it's too much overhead, btw VectorDrawableCompat already contains cached bitmap

Comment: this is the only way,  and no, do not use any reflection to get the cache as it can be changed in any future

Comment: @pskink reflection is dangerous anyway, but in this case is way much cheaper because i working with really large vector and creating bitmaps in UI thread could cause noticeable lags as well as pressure on GC

Comment: come on you dont have to create your Bitmap with the full Drawable size,  in a case you want one pixel make it 1x1

Comment: in a case you need some x,  y position and n surrounding  pixels, make it (2n + 1) x (2n +1)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use reflection for access field `VectorDrawableCompat.mVectorState` and get cached bitmap from property `mCachedBitmap`

Something like that:

```
     public static int getColorAt(VectorDrawableCompat drawable, float x, float y) {
        try {
            final Field field = drawable.getClass().getDeclaredField("mVectorState");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final Object state = field.get(drawable);
            final Field bitmapField = state.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCachedBitmap");
            bitmapField.setAccessible(true);
            final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bitmapField.get(state);
            return bitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: i have no idea why "reflection" based solutions are always so appreciated, you should never do that unless you want to have problems in the future

Comment: You are right, but if you don't have any other ways it's still bad, but working solution, but yes, you can get problems in future, but Support Library is just dependency, not a part of framework, so you can control updates and don't worry about eventual class realization changes

Comment: you have other ways,  call `Drawable#draw`, BTW do you know that support library does **not** use `mCachedBitmap` if it is run on the platforms that have `VectorDrawable` (API 5+) and just uses the native implementation? of course you can disable that changing the sources but then you could also just add the method `getCachedBitmap` / `getPixel` / whatever - so the reflection is not needed in that case